# C# Flipping Surface Normals

Tags: c#, mesh

I need to do a boolean subtraction between two models in C#. One of the meshs will be entirely within the other mesh, so I was hoping to reverse the normals for the one model and add the two models together. I am at a loss on how to invert the normals though.

This is how I'm calculating a surface normal:

```
//creates surface normals
    Vector3D CalculateSurfaceNormal(Point3D p1, Point3D p2, Point3D p3)
    {
        Vector3D v1 = new Vector3D(0, 0, 0);             // Vector 1 (x,y,z) & Vector 2 (x,y,z)
        Vector3D v2 = new Vector3D(0, 0, 0);
        Vector3D normal = new Vector3D(0, 0, 0);

        // Finds The Vector Between 2 Points By Subtracting
        // The x,y,z Coordinates From One Point To Another.

        // Calculate The Vector From Point 2 To Point 1
        v1.X = p1.X - p2.X;                  
        v1.Y = p1.Y - p2.Y;                  
        v1.Z = p1.Z - p2.Z;                  
        // Calculate The Vector From Point 3 To Point 2
        v2.X = p2.X - p3.X;                  
        v2.Y = p2.Y - p3.Y;                  
        v2.Z = p2.Z - p3.Z;                  

        // Compute The Cross Product To Give Us A Surface Normal
        normal.X = v1.Y * v2.Z - v1.Z * v2.Y;   // Cross Product For Y - Z
        normal.Y = v1.Z * v2.X - v1.X * v2.Z;   // Cross Product For X - Z
        normal.Z = v1.X * v2.Y - v1.Y * v2.X;   // Cross Product For X - Y

        normal.Normalize();

        return normal;
    }
```

I was advised to reverse the normal by negating it:

```
n = CalculateSurfaceNormal(p1, p2, p3);
n = new Vector3D(-1 * n.X, -1 * n.Y, -1 * n.Z);
```

I find the values are negated, but when I view the model in a 3D program, there is no change in the model.

Another suggestion was to try backface culling by changing the order of the vectors. I tried this by swapping the order of v1 and v2:

```
//creates invertedsurface normals
    Vector3D CalculateInvertedSurfaceNormal(Point3D p1, Point3D p2, Point3D p3)
    {
        Vector3D v1 = new Vector3D(0, 0, 0);             // Vector 1 (x,y,z) & Vector 2 (x,y,z)
        Vector3D v2 = new Vector3D(0, 0, 0);
        Vector3D normal = new Vector3D(0, 0, 0);

        // Finds The Vector Between 2 Points By Subtracting
        // The x,y,z Coordinates From One Point To Another.

        // Calculate The Vector From Point 2 To Point 1
        v2.X = p1.X - p2.X;
        v2.Y = p1.Y - p2.Y;
        v2.Z = p1.Z - p2.Z;
        // Calculate The Vector From Point 3 To Point 2
        v1.X = p2.X - p3.X;
        v1.Y = p2.Y - p3.Y;
        v1.Z = p2.Z - p3.Z;

        // Compute The Cross Product To Give Us A Surface Normal
        normal.X = v1.Y * v2.Z - v1.Z * v2.Y;   // Cross Product For Y - Z
        normal.Y = v1.Z * v2.X - v1.X * v2.Z;   // Cross Product For X - Z
        normal.Z = v1.X * v2.Y - v1.Y * v2.X;   // Cross Product For X - Y

        normal.Normalize();

        return normal;
    }
```

No change in the model.

Here is the whole code:

```
    private void SaveMoldMeshtoStlFile(MeshGeometry3D mesh, string filename)
    {
        if (mesh == null)
            return;

        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            File.SetAttributes(filename, FileAttributes.Normal);
            File.Delete(filename);
        }

        Point3DCollection vertexes = mesh.Positions;
        Int32Collection indexes = mesh.TriangleIndices;

        Point3D p1, p2, p3;
        Vector3D n;

        string text;

        using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("solid Bolus");

            for (int v = 0; v < mesh.TriangleIndices.Count(); v += 3)
            {
                //gather the 3 points for the face and the normal
                p1 = vertexes[indexes[v]];
                p2 = vertexes[indexes[v + 1]];
                p3 = vertexes[indexes[v + 2]];
                n = CalculateInvertedSurfaceNormal(p1, p2, p3);

                text = string.Format("facet normal {0} {1} {2}", n.X,n.Y, n.Z);
                writer.WriteLine(text);
                writer.WriteLine("outer loop");
                text = String.Format("vertex {0} {1} {2}", p1.X, p1.Y, p1.Z);
                writer.WriteLine(text);
                text = String.Format("vertex {0} {1} {2}", p2.X, p2.Y, p2.Z);
                writer.WriteLine(text);
                text = String.Format("vertex {0} {1} {2}", p3.X, p3.Y, p3.Z);
                writer.WriteLine(text);
                writer.WriteLine("endloop");
                writer.WriteLine("endfacet");

            }


        }
    }

    //creates inverted surface normals
    Vector3D CalculateInvertedSurfaceNormal(Point3D p1, Point3D p2, Point3D p3)
    {
        Vector3D v1 = new Vector3D(0, 0, 0);             // Vector 1 (x,y,z) & Vector 2 (x,y,z)
        Vector3D v2 = new Vector3D(0, 0, 0);
        Vector3D normal = new Vector3D(0, 0, 0);

        // Finds The Vector Between 2 Points By Subtracting
        // The x,y,z Coordinates From One Point To Another.

        // Calculate The Vector From Point 2 To Point 1
        v2.X = p1.X - p2.X;
        v2.Y = p1.Y - p2.Y;
        v2.Z = p1.Z - p2.Z;
        // Calculate The Vector From Point 3 To Point 2
        v1.X = p2.X - p3.X;
        v1.Y = p2.Y - p3.Y;
        v1.Z = p2.Z - p3.Z;

        // Compute The Cross Product To Give Us A Surface Normal
        normal.X = v1.Y * v2.Z - v1.Z * v2.Y;   // Cross Product For Y - Z
        normal.Y = v1.Z * v2.X - v1.X * v2.Z;   // Cross Product For X - Z
        normal.Z = v1.X * v2.Y - v1.Y * v2.X;   // Cross Product For X - Y

        normal.Normalize();

        return normal;
    }
```

Is there an error with my code?  Am I missing something?  I've tried out the exported models in a few different programs, and all are showing the exported model still has the normals facing outwards.  I tried flipping the normals in Blender and found the other programs also showed the normals flipped, so I'm fairly sure it's a problem with my program.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the solution.

The order of points for each triangle is crucial.  If the order of points doesn't support the normal's direction, I'm finding other programs will automatically correct the normal.

Where I had this:

```
//gather the 3 points for the face and the normal
            p1 = vertexes[indexes[v]];
            p2 = vertexes[indexes[v + 1]];
            p3 = vertexes[indexes[v + 2]];
            n = CalculateInvertedSurfaceNormal(p1, p2, p3);
```

I instead reversed the direction of the points by changed to this:

```
//gather the 3 points for the face and the normal
            p3 = vertexes[indexes[v]];
            p2 = vertexes[indexes[v + 1]];
            p1 = vertexes[indexes[v + 2]];
            n = CalculateInvertedSurfaceNormal(p1, p2, p3);
```

That solved my problem.